# How to add a config value / environment variable to a cloudControl deployment using the API

Tags: cloudcontrol

I would like to add an environment variable, also called config in this context, to my cloudControl deployment. However, I can't use the provided command-line tool `cctrlapp`, but have to use the REST API. Their API can be accessed at https://api.cloudcontrol.com and is documented at https://api.cloudcontrol.com/doc/.

My problem now is that the section of the documentation that refers to the environment variables is empty!

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Application of the type nodejs created
2. Default deployment created
3. Tried to add the env. variable

I figured out that I would have to send a POST request to `https://api.cloudcontrol.com/app/{APP_NAME}/deployment/{DEPLOYMENT_NAME}/addon`. According to the implementation of `cctrlapp` (see [app.py](https://github.com/cloudControl/cctrl/blob/master/cctrl/app.py) and [cclib.py](https://github.com/cloudControl/pycclib/blob/master/pycclib/cclib.py)) I would infer the following JSON data is required:

```
{"addon":"config.free","options":{"key":"value"}}
```

Now I'm stuck.
In this case, the request returns:

```
Bad Request {"parameters": "Invalid parameters given."}
```

If I use a slightly modified object

```
{"addon":"config.free","settings":{"key":"value"}}
```

I receive this message:

```
[ERROR] Missing config variables
```

Does anyone know how to apply such a key-value pair using only the API?

Comment: Did you try to url-encode the options? Something like `https://api.cloudcontrol.com/app/{APP_NAME}/deployment/{DEPLOYMENT_NAME}/addon?options='{"key": "value"}'`?

Also, note that if the add-on is already added, you need to send a PUT requests and encode your vars as `settings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at https://github.com/cloudControl/pycclib/blob/master/pycclib/cclib.py#L422, I think you do need to use `"options"` and the value of `options` should be a json encoded dictionary (https://github.com/cloudControl/cctrl/blob/master/cctrl/addonoptionhelpers.py#L82).

The remaining parts are not json encoded however, but are just normal POST parameters (https://github.com/cloudControl/pycclib/blob/master/pycclib/cclib.py#L931). A working request for reference (equivalent to config.add x=1):

```
POST /app/myappname/deployment/default/addon/ HTTP/1.1
content-length: 50
accept-encoding: compress, gzip
user-agent: pycclib/1.5.5
host: api.cloudcontrolled.com
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
authorization: cc_auth_token="thetoken"

options=%7B%22x%22%3A+%221%22%7D&addon=config.free
```